# FreqDist in NLTK not sorting output

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to teach myself language processing. NLTK in python has a function called FreqDist that gives the frequency of words in a text, but for some reason it's not working properly.

This is what the tutorial has me write:

```
fdist1 = FreqDist(text1)
vocabulary1 = fdist1.keys()
vocabulary1[:50]
```

So basically it's supposed to give me a list of the 50 most frequent words in the text. When I run the code, though, the result is the 50 *least* frequent words in order of least frequent to most frequent, as opposed to the other way around. The output I am getting is as follows:

```
[u'succour', u'four', u'woods', u'hanging', u'woody', u'conjure', u'looking', u'eligible', u'scold', u'unsuitableness', u'meadows', u'stipulate', u'leisurely', u'bringing', u'disturb', u'internally', u'hostess', u'mohrs', u'persisted', u'Does', u'succession', u'tired', u'cordially', u'pulse', u'elegant', u'second', u'sooth', u'shrugging', u'abundantly', u'errors', u'forgetting', u'contributed', u'fingers', u'increasing', u'exclamations', u'hero', u'leaning', u'Truth', u'here', u'china', u'hers', u'natured', u'substance', u'unwillingness...]
```

I'm copying the tutorial exactly, but I must be doing something wrong.

Here is the link to the tutorial:

http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#sec-computing-with-language-texts-and-words

The example is right under the heading "Figure 1.3: Counting Words Appearing in a Text (a frequency distribution)"

Does anyone know how I might fix this?

Comment: So is this your output: `['wonderingly', 'wonderments', 'wondrousness', 'wonst', 'woodcock', 'wooded', 'woodland', 'woodpecker', 'woody', 'wooing', 'woracious', 'wordless', 'worker', 'workers', 'workmen', 'worldly', 'worming', 'worried', 'worryings', 'wounding', 'wounds', 'wrangling', 'wrap', 'wrapall', 'wrapping', 'wreak', 'wreath', 'wrestling', 'wrestlings', 'wretchedly', 'wriggles', 'wring', 'wrinkling', 'writhed', 'wrung', 'yawed', 'yawing', 'yawingly', 'yearly', 'yokes', 'yoking', 'youngest', 'youngish', 'yourselbs', 'zag', 'zay', 'zephyr', 'zig', 'zoned', 'zoology']`?

Comment: Or is the order reversed? Or are you getting something else entirely?

Comment: I'm getting this: [u'succour', u'four', u'woods', u'hanging', u'woody', u'conjure', u'looking', u'eligible', u'scold', u'unsuitableness', u'meadows', u'stipulate', u'leisurely', u'bringing', u'disturb', u'internally', u'hostess', u'mohrs', u'persisted', u'Does', u'succession', u'tired', u'cordially', u'pulse', u'elegant', u'second', u'sooth', u'shrugging', u'abundantly', u'errors', u'forgetting', u'contributed', u'fingers', u'increasing', u'exclamations', u'hero', u'leaning', u'Truth', u'here', u'china', u'hers', u'natured', u'substance', u'unwillingness...]

Comment: I think yours is the last fifty words alphabetically. I could be wrong but what it looks like I'm getting is the words that appear in the text the least number of times

Comment: You might want to check your `text1`. How do you define `text1`? I do get your output in your most recent comment (the output you are looking for) when I run the code in your post. The output in my first comment is the last fifty words of the same text (as ordered by `FreqDist`).

Comment: I imported the texts from the tutorial and text1 is `<Text: Moby Dick by Herman Melville 1851>`

Comment: What happens when you run the code from my answer below **in a new shell**? (I am posting the code there because I am allowed more space there.) Do you get the same output? (I am wondering if `text1` has somehow been modified?

Comment: See my answer below. Somehow you appear to have inadvertently changed `text1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is old. Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27464892/1775603) instead.

In order to troubleshoot this issue, I would recommend taking the following steps:

**1. Check which version of `nltk` you are using**:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> print nltk.__version__
2.0.4  # preferably 2.0 or higher
```

Older versions of `nltk` do not have a sortable `FreqDist.keys` method.

**2. Verify that you have not inadvertently modified `text1` or `vocabulary1`**:

Open a new shell and start the process over again from the beginning:

```
>>> from nltk.book import *
*** Introductory Examples for the NLTK Book ***
Loading text1, ..., text9 and sent1, ..., sent9
Type the name of the text or sentence to view it.
Type: 'texts()' or 'sents()' to list the materials.
text1: Moby Dick by Herman Melville 1851
text2: Sense and Sensibility by Jane Austen 1811
text3: The Book of Genesis
text4: Inaugural Address Corpus
text5: Chat Corpus
text6: Monty Python and the Holy Grail
text7: Wall Street Journal
text8: Personals Corpus
text9: The Man Who Was Thursday by G . K . Chesterton 1908
>>> from nltk import FreqDist
>>> fdist1 = FreqDist(text1)
>>> vocabulary1 = fdist1.keys()
>>> vocabulary1[:50]
[',', 'the', '.', 'of', 'and', 'a', 'to', ';', 'in', 'that', "'", '-', 'his', 'it', 'I', 's', 'is', 'he', 'with', 'was', 'as', '"', 'all', 'for', 'this', '!', 'at', 'by', 'but', 'not', '--', 'him', 'from', 'be', 'on', 'so', 'whale', 'one', 'you', 'had', 'have', 'there', 'But', 'or', 'were', 'now', 'which', '?', 'me', 'like']
```

Note that vocabulary1 should not contain the string `u'succour'` (the first unicode string in the output of your original post):

```
>>> vocabulary1.count(u'succour')  # vocabulary1 does **not** contain the string u'succour'
0
```

**3. If you are still having trouble, inspect your source code and text lists to make sure they match what you see below**:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> print inspect.getsource(FreqDist.keys)  # make sure your source code matches the source code below
    def keys(self):
        """
        Return the samples sorted in decreasing order of frequency.

        :rtype: list(any)
        """
        self._sort_keys_by_value()
        return map(itemgetter(0), self._item_cache)

>>> print inspect.getsource(FreqDist._sort_keys_by_value)  # and matches this source code
    def _sort_keys_by_value(self):
        if not self._item_cache:
            self._item_cache = sorted(dict.items(self), key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))  # <= check this line especially

>>> text1[:40]  # does the first part of your text list match this one?
['[', 'Moby', 'Dick', 'by', 'Herman', 'Melville', '1851', ']', 'ETYMOLOGY', '.', '(', 'Supplied', 'by', 'a', 'Late', 'Consumptive', 'Usher', 'to', 'a', 'Grammar', 'School', ')', 'The', 'pale', 'Usher', '--', 'threadbare', 'in', 'coat', ',', 'heart', ',', 'body', ',', 'and', 'brain', ';', 'I', 'see', 'him']

>>> text1[-40:]  # and what about the end of your text list?
['second', 'day', ',', 'a', 'sail', 'drew', 'near', ',', 'nearer', ',', 'and', 'picked', 'me', 'up', 'at', 'last', '.', 'It', 'was', 'the', 'devious', '-', 'cruising', 'Rachel', ',', 'that', 'in', 'her', 'retracing', 'search', 'after', 'her', 'missing', 'children', ',', 'only', 'found', 'another', 'orphan', '.']
```

If your source code or text lists do not match the above exactly, consider re-installing `nltk` with the most recent stable version.

Comment: I did what you said and got a different output, but it's still not right :(

`[u'funereal', u'unscientific', u'divinely', u'foul', u'four', u'gag', u'prefix', u'woods', u'clotted', u'Duck', u'hanging', u'plaudits', u'woody', u'Until', u'marching', u'disobeying', u'canes', u'granting', u'advantage', u'Westers', u'insertion', u'DRYDEN', u'formless', u'Untried', u'superficially', u'Western', u'portentous', u'meadows', u'sinking', u'Ding', u'Spurn', u'treasuries', u'churned', u'oceans', u'invasion', u'powders', u'tinkerings', u'tantalizing', u'yellow'...]`

Comment: @user3528925 Sorry to hear that. I added four further steps you might take to troubleshoot this problem to the answer above. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: The beginning and end of the text are exactly the same as the ones you showed. I tried running the first part you wrote but it's giving me a syntax error

Comment: @user3528925 Make sure you only copy the first line of each `inspect.getsource()` call. So this would be the entirety of the script: line 1: `import inspect`, line 2: `from nltk import FreqDist`, line 3: `print inspect.getsource(FreqDist.keys)`.

Comment: @user3528925 Just out of curiosity, when you type `import nltk` and then (on the next line) `print nltk.__version__`, what output do you get?

Answer (score 40):

From [NLTK's GitHub](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/390#issuecomment-53171900):

> FreqDist in NLTK3 is a wrapper for collections.Counter; Counter provides `most_common()` method to return items in order. `FreqDist.keys()` method is provided by standard library; it is not overridden. I think it is good we're becoming more compatible with stdlib.
>
> docs at googlecode are very old, they are from 2011. More up-to-date docs can be found on http://nltk.org website.

So for NLKT version 3, instead of `fdist1.keys()[:50]`, use `fdist1.most_common(50)`.

The [tutorial](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#frequency-distributions) has also been updated:

```
fdist1 = FreqDist(text1)
>>> print(fdist1)
<FreqDist with 19317 samples and 260819 outcomes>
>>> fdist1.most_common(50)
[(',', 18713), ('the', 13721), ('.', 6862), ('of', 6536), ('and', 6024),
('a', 4569), ('to', 4542), (';', 4072), ('in', 3916), ('that', 2982),
("'", 2684), ('-', 2552), ('his', 2459), ('it', 2209), ('I', 2124),
('s', 1739), ('is', 1695), ('he', 1661), ('with', 1659), ('was', 1632),
('as', 1620), ('"', 1478), ('all', 1462), ('for', 1414), ('this', 1280),
('!', 1269), ('at', 1231), ('by', 1137), ('but', 1113), ('not', 1103),
('--', 1070), ('him', 1058), ('from', 1052), ('be', 1030), ('on', 1005),
('so', 918), ('whale', 906), ('one', 889), ('you', 841), ('had', 767),
('have', 760), ('there', 715), ('But', 705), ('or', 697), ('were', 680),
('now', 646), ('which', 640), ('?', 637), ('me', 627), ('like', 624)]
>>> fdist1['whale']
906
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo, I also struggled with the same problem with @user3528925 and your answer helped. My NLTK version is also 3.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to using FreqDist, you can simply use `Counter` from `collections, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952069/how-to-get-the-rank-of-a-word-from-a-dictionary-with-word-frequencies-python/22953416#22953416 :

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> text = """foo foo bar bar foo bar hello bar hello world  hello world hello world hello world  hello world hello hello hello"""
>>> dictionary = Counter(text.split())
>>> dictionary
{"foo":3, "bar":4, "hello":9, "world":5}
>>> dictionary.most_common()
[('hello', 9), ('world', 5), ('bar', 4), ('foo', 3)]
>>> [i[0] for i in dictionary.most_common()]
['hello', 'world', 'bar', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import nltk
fdist1 = nltk.FreqDist(text)
```

fdist1 contains 'key' - for words, 'values' - for frequency count of words.

The above variable fdist1 is not sorted hence it will not print top 50 results based on the command. Please use the following code to first sort them:

```
sorted_fdist1 = sorted(fdist1 , key = fdist1.__getitem__, reverse = True)
sorted_fdist1[0:50]
```

This will print out the top 50 frequent words.

Comment: What is freq_dist ?

Comment: @NadavB It's a typo. Try this `sorted_fdist1 = sorted(fdist1 , key = fdist1.__getitem__, reverse = True)`. I just fixed that in the answer!